# Error changing Windows Media Player component fullscreen property

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I'm testing Windows Media player component in C#. At runtime my project receives the error :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))'

when I'm changing `fullscreen` property

The related code line:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
```

What's the reason?

Comment: The only thing catastrophic here is the quality of the error reporting, WMP does not win a lot of prizes  There are two ways to use this COM component.  As a child control embedded in a form, like you do now, wrapped by AxHost.  Or as a way to automate the existing player program, as an "out of process" server, no AxHost wrapper required.  Only the latter can be made full screen, the control must stay embedded in the form.  Consider maximizing the form.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your elegant point. So you mean when embedded in a form,WMP control CAN'T be in fullscreen mode?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I myself solved the problem: the embedded WMP control CAN BE maximized IF it's playing,so the following code MUST be used:

```
        if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
```

Now the catastrophic error has gone:)